# Select into a temporary table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to do something like the following,

```
select * into temp from (select * from student);
```

It gives me the following error,

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

In my real example the subquery (select * from student) is more complex.

I want to use this in a stored procedure, so I don't want to create the table itself. I just want to make my code more readable by using a temp table.

Comment: I voted up this answer because something like this is possible in SQL Server: To Select a result set into a table that doesn't exist, thus creating a temporary table. E.G> SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM STUDENT

Comment: You don't `select into` a table in Oracle, you `insert into` it. The `select into` construction is for populating a variable. It's unfortunate that other vendors have a similar looking syntax for something unrelated.

Answer (score 13):

Then perhaps you need to do something like this:

```
declare
   type t_temp_storage is table of student%rowtype;
   my_temp_storage t_temp_storage;
begin
   select * bulk collect into my_temp_storage from student;
   for i in 1..my_temp_storage.count
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line('here I am '||my_temp_storage(i).stuid);
   end loop; 
 end;
```

Answer (score 9):

If the table temp does not exist, you have to create it.

```
 CREATE TABLE temp as
    SELECT * FROM student;
```

Comment: This table `temp` is not really a temporary table, but a real physical table/

Answer (score 5):

I found useful this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_CONDITION
)
```

The clause ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS overrides the default one (ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS). If you keep the default the records will be deleted at every commit, so if you work with an auto-commit client the records will be deleted immediately after creation. In both cases anyway the table exists only for the duration of the session.

Comment: What if two clients calls procedure at the same time? Is it possible that this global table is created inside each session separately?

Comment: They are the same, as they are declared as Global, so all user from all sessions can see it. To create per session, use PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLES, look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-23B23DCF-7482-4585-9C63-AC073C5DE224

Comment: By creating this temporary table, the table as such is preserved right? Unlike the SQL Server Temp tables, it wont be auto dropped, correct? What is the way to have a temporary table space that can hold data, until we do some other steps, then use the data from temp table and drop it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't "select" into a temp table.  If you want to insert into a temp table from the results of a select:

```
insert into temp
select * from student;
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: You have to create the temp table first, just like any other table in oracle.  If you want to create a table based on a select, then use "create table xxx as select ..."  But that can only be done once.

Comment: I don't want to have the table. It is costly in terms of coding to create the table itself for every temp variable I need. I just want to have something dynamic that I can fill with on the go in the stored procedure. And after the stored procedure terminates, get rid of it. But I am not sure whether it is possible or not in Oracle.

Comment: Well, that is not how I understood the question.  If you need a temporary structure to store stuff in pl/sql, you can use pl/sql collections (also called tables unfortunately) See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005)

Comment: Do you still need to specify the column names and the types before using the collection?

Comment: I would suggest to spend some time reading the documentation for clarity.

Comment: In SQL Server this is possible, if you are asking whether there is an equivalent in oracle, I would also be interested to know the answer,