# Creating a temporary table using Oracle SQL in Sql Server Report Builder 3.0

Tags: oracle11g, common-table-expression, temp-tables, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following issue:

I want to create a report in Report Builder 3.0 that uses an Oracle 11g DB. The statements involved is the creation and population of a temp table and a query in that table in order to filter the data.

The actual query is unimportant (quite complex and due to NDA reasons and-the-like although cannot actually reproduced I would not like to include it as-is) but in blocks the whole process is the following:

```
--table  creation query
create table a as
    with b as (
       select * from c )
    select * from b
    left join d;
--query on that table
select * from b where condition;
```

I have a similar task to do with an Sybase IQ in which I can use

```
select into #temp
```

but Oracle does not support this (at least directly).

The problem is that the text-based query editor of SQL Server Report Builder does not support and sorts of "create/declare local/global temporary table" statements which is no problem for SQL Server and Sybase IQ which I frequently use but with Oracle I cannot find a workaround.

[image: See Error]

Keep in mind that the actual "with" statement and subsequent selects and joins are really complex so any solution like the following suggested

[Select into a temporary table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653276/select-into-a-temporary-table-in-oracle)

is unfortunately not feasible.

Any suggestions? (Of course nested with's would be perfect but *sigh*)

Comment: What if you pre created a Global Temporary Table (GTT) and simply inserted into that?

Comment: Not an option unfortunately. I am trying to devise a way to make it work with subsequent "with" clauses (going to try this out tomorrow) but given the data I have it is unlikely to work

Comment: OK, then I'm not sure what specific problem you are trying to solve. I looked like you were saying the MS SQL Server report build does not support CREATE...

Comment: Oracle does not support select into #temp and report builder does not support create. Thats the issue

Comment: Well, then why not a GTT? Then you can have the report builder do... insert into <temp_gtt> select ... <with clause etc >