# How to save data after using With Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to save the data I have after With Clause. Maybe saving into TEMP table or some other data set.

```
WITH TASKLIST AS
 (SELECT * FROM IC_V_NEWSKUSTASKLIST WHERE MSTID IS NULL),
RESULTS AS
 (SELECT *
    FROM ICTASK
    LEFT JOIN TASKLIST
      ON ICTASK.SOURCETABLEID = TASKLIST.SOURCETABLEID)
SELECT * FROM RESULTS;
```

I want to save RESULTS data into some other table in stand of SELECT them, but the select statement is mandatory after WITH clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select into a temporary table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653276/select-into-a-temporary-table-in-oracle)

Comment: No it didn't solve my question

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT` statement if it allows to redirect the output?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are different DB Management Systems. Leave only one of them tagged(Indeed PLSQL suggests Oracle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTAS (Create Table As Select) is one option:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    with
  3    tasklist as
  4      (select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  5       from emp
  6      ),
  7    results as
  8      (select d.dname, t.deptno, t.ename
  9       from tasklist t join dept d on d.deptno = t.deptno
 10       where t.deptno = 10
 11      )
 12    select * from results;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;

DNAME              DEPTNO ENAME
-------------- ---------- ----------
ACCOUNTING             10 CLARK
ACCOUNTING             10 KING
ACCOUNTING             10 MILLER

SQL>
```